# How do I open/restore a progress database .bup file?

Tags: database, database-restore, progress-db

I have a .bup file which is supposed to be Progress database file. My question is, how can I open/restore it and look at the data?

Answer (score 3):

You need to have Progress installed. In it you will find a command: `prorest` run from command line that will help you restore a previously backed up database. At least if it has been backed up using the built in back up command (probkup).

To make things easier for yourself you could start the Progress command line environment (it should be in the bin directory in your installation path). Simply run `proenv` to start that and then follow the steps below. If on Windows you will most likely find proenv in your Start menu.

Basic syntax:

```
prorest [new database] [archive]
```

so for example

```
prorest c:\temp\mynewdatabase file.bup
```

After that you can connect to the database using Progress built in commands. You might find more help at:
[Progress KnowledgeBase](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/)
and
[Progress communities](http://communities.progress.com/pcom/index.jspa).

A specific description of the prorest command can be found here: [Progress KnowledgeBase Article 99033](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/P99033?retURL=/apex/ProgressKBHome&popup=false)

Comment: The ".bup" filename extension is probably a local convention.  (There is no standard.)

Comment: It is also possible that there is more than 1 "extent" making up the complete backup.  If you get prompted for the next file or device prorest is telling you that it is a multi-extent backup.  Usually the additional extents are named something like .bup2, .bup3 etc. (but, again, the names are arbitrary and there is no convention).  The list of additional files to be restored /can/ be in a file and redirection used to avoid having to type them all in.  The first backup extent name must be on the command line, subsequent extents are either entered manually or via file redirection.

Comment: Thanks for your replies, very valueable. WHen I run prorest I get this message: Version number mismatch, backup has 4246, database has 4269. (16691). I guess the backup is made with a different version than I have currently installed (11.2),

Comment: That's correct. You might have older utils installed, check for a subdirectory called version10utils or similar - don't remember right now and not on a system with Progress installed. Best would be if you had version 10 installed. Then you can restore and use version 11 to convert. Again: check the knowledgebase or community. Lot's of help there!

Comment: I havent tried this myself but look at [this article](http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000029439?retURL=%2Fapex%2Fprogresskbsearch&popup=false). Syntax should be something like INSTALL-PATH/bin/102dbutils/102b05_dbutil prorest newdb archive.bkup (this might differ - in my installation on Linux I have old utilities from versions 8.3, 9.1, 10.1 and 10.2 but on Windows I have none - perhaps a licensing thing). If all else fails - contact [Progress support](http://www.progress.com)

Comment: I have the 102dbutils folder with 102b05_util. When I rung the suggested command I get: msgOpen: unable to open message file: PROMSGS

Comment: Start with the proenv script to get your environment set up

Comment: When I used proenv the error was gone. But it wants a .db file, and I have a .bup file. When i run: "proenv>.\Progress\OpenEdge\bin\102dbutils\102b05_dbutil.exe prostrc repair C:\mybackupfile" I get "PROSTRCT REPAIR: cannot read file C:\mybackupfile.st, commando ignored. (6918)"

Comment: Try 102b05_dbutil prorest newdb yourbackup.bkup

Comment: ** The database have wrong version number. (db: 4269, pro: 4246). (44)

Comment: Try the utility in 101dbutils instead.

Comment: Then I get: Unable to complete version 161 restore with a version 178 backup.

Comment: I think you will need to contact support. The versions AND the OS need to match. You won't for instance be able to restore a backup from a solaris database to a linux/windows database.